# Linker can't find mathgl library

Tags: c++, linker, g++, ld, archlinux

I try to make `mathgl` work, but the linker can't find the library. I installed it through the user repository from arch linux.
I just copied the example program:

```
#include <mgl2/mgl.h>
int main()
{
  mglGraph gr;
  gr.FPlot("sin(pi*x)");
  gr.WriteFrame("test.png");
}
```

The official website states you need to link `lmgl`, but I get this error:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -lmgl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmgl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I couldn't figure out where to start looking for the library. How can I see where it was installed?

I was looking for `libmgl` with `ldconfig -p` getting these results:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libmgl    
    libmgl2.so.7.5.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmgl2.so.7.5.0
    libmgl2.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmgl2.so
    libmgl2-qt5.so.7.5.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmgl2-qt5.so.7.5.0
    libmgl2-qt5.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmgl2-qt5.so
    libmgl2-qt.so.7.5.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmgl2-qt.so.7.5.0
    libmgl2-qt.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmgl2-qt.so
    libmgl2-glut.so.7.5.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmgl2-glut.so.7.5.0
    libmgl2-glut.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmgl2-glut.so
```

Comment: Did you put arch tag for arch linux or python package? Please read the tag description before adding it into your post.

Comment: Does `/usr/lib/libmgl.a` exist?

Comment: So, you could try `-lmgl2`

Comment: @Incomputable thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amadeus indicated, using

```
$ g++ main.cpp -lmgl2
```

should work.